# DigitalOcean Function "Nothing Deployed"

Tags: function, digital-ocean

I built and deployed some functions several weeks ago. What's there runs great, but I made some minor changes and they will not deploy. Neither of these work:

`doctl serverless watch packages/utilities/send-mail`

`doctl serverless deploy packages/utilities/send-mail`

I just see this:

```
Watching 'packages/utilities/send-mail' [use Control-C to terminate]

Deploying 'packages/utilities/send-mail' due to change in 'packages/utilities/send-mail/send-mail.js'

Nothing deployed
Deployment complete.  Resuming watch.
```

No errors. No updates.

project.yml

```yaml
parameters: {}
environment: {}
packages:
    - name: utilities
      shared: false
      environment: {}
      parameters: {}
      annotations: {}
      functions:
        - name: send-mail
          binary: false
          main: ""
          runtime: nodejs:18
          web: true
          webSecure: false
          parameters: {}
          environment: {
            MAIL_HOST: ${MAIL_HOST},
            MAIL_USER: ${MAIL_USER},
            MAIL_PASS: ${MAIL_PASS}
          }
          annotations: {}
          limits: {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the path with a dot. You must watch/deploy the project directory, not the function directory.

`doctl serverless deploy .`

*Edited: Hat tip to Matt.*

Comment: Should clarify that the reason this is the fix is because the directory you must watch/deploy is the project's directory, not the function's directory. Usually people open their terminals to the directory of the entire project, so that's why `.` in particular works well if they're doing that.